# Rotate a canvas using Layout Transform

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to rotate this canvas

```
            <Canvas Canvas.Left="203" Canvas.Top="274" Name="canvas1" Height="0" Width="0" >
                <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-45"/>
                </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
```

I want to rotate this canvas but in the same position.. check this image[image]

The left image I dont want to do that.. I need to create the second one.. but always I need to set X, Y values? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In WPF, has two properties to support display transformations, `LayoutTransform` and `RenderTransform`.Any Transform assigned to LayoutTransform is applied when layout is performed. RenderTransform is applied after layout when rendering is performed.

You need to change the Transformation to RenderTransform

```
       <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-45"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
```

You can see the difference between [LayoutTransform and RenderTransform.](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2008/12/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-whats-the-difference/)

Comment: This doesn't tell the whole story. Why should `RenderTransform` (correctly) pick the centre of the object as it has done here, as the centre of rotation? I figure it's likely to depend on where you start the draw operation from. In other words, how does the RenderTransform 'know' where the centre is? I suspect the answer is that it doesn't. You can use `RenderTransformOrigin` to tell the transformation engine where the centre of rotation is relative to the bounds of the object.

Comment: @Tom: Thank you for your valuable information.We can use the `RenderTransformOrigin` to the center of the element even if you do not know its size.